# Why does storing a ReactiveVar in Session convert it to a plain Object?

Tags: javascript, meteor

If I store a `ReactiveVar` in `Session` and then read it, I see that my `ReactiveVar` gets converted to an Object.

```
var v = new ReactiveVar(4)
Session.set("v", v)
Session.get("v") //Object {curValue: 4, dep: Object}
```

I can't `get` or `set` it any more because it is a plain object.
Does anybody know the point of it?

PS: `ReactiveVar` inside another `ReactiveVar` works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) is a [global named `ReactiveDict`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/session/session.js#L1).
All reactive dictionaries have a very funny feature : They [stringify](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js#L61) your data for storage.
They do so in order to store it across hot code pushes for example.

Consider the following code :

```
var dict = new ReactiveDict()
dict.set('foo', { func : function() {} })
console.log(dict.get('foo'))
```

The console will output :

> `Object {  }`

And that is because [EJSON stringification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ejson/ejson.js#L338) (defined by Meteor) is based off [JSON stringification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which removes object methods **and prototypes** to strictly keep data.

If you want to store a reactive value coming from a `ReactiveVar` into `Session`, you will have to run a [`Tracker`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker) computation to do it :

```
Tracer.autorun(
  () => Session.set('foo', foo.get()) 
)
```

If you want to reactively store an object with methods or a defined prototype, use `ReactiveVar`.